# How do you view only the final output in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, view, output

I wanted to know if it is possible to only display the final called function's output in CodeIgniter?

For example, in the below code, when the user is at the index method (/goose/index), they will see the outputs from both views 'foo1' and 'foo2'.

What I would like to achieve is only see the output of the final view (i.e. 'foo2').  Just wondering if this is possible to do this without using a redirect().

```php
class Goose extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();          
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->foo1();
    }

    public function foo1()
    {           
        $this->load->view('foo1');
        $this->foo2();
        //redirect(base_url('index.php/goose/foo2'));
    }


    public function foo2()
    {       
        $this->load->view('foo2');
    }

}
```

Thank you.

V

Comment: okay.. so you want to call foo1, but you dont want to load the foo1 view.. instead you want to load the foo2 view... is that all youre doing, are you just loading views? is there any data that needs to be passed?

Comment: Yes, that's right. just loading the final view which in this case is foo2()

Comment: so why would the answer below not work? are there any other constraints or restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put an argument in on your function it should works

```
public function index()
{
    $this->foo1(false);
}

public function foo1($flag = true)
{
    if ($flag) {
        $this->load->view('foo1');
    }

    $this->foo2();        
}
```

Comment: @VeeDee this will load both view for `'/goose/foo1'` and it will only load view `foo2` for `'/goose/index'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this

```
class Goose extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();          
}

public function index()//if user comes by /goose/index it will load both view or call both function
{
    //call both function for index
    $this->foo1();
    $this->foo2();
    //or call only both views
    //$this->load->view('foo1');   
   // $this->load->view('foo2');

   //or call only desired function or view
}

public function foo1()//if user comes with /goose/foo1 will load only foo1 view
{           
    $this->load->view('foo1');       
}
public function foo2()//if user comes with /goose/foo2 will load foo2 view
{       
    $this->load->view('foo2');
}
```

}

Comment: I dont think he want that.